# Automatically send private applications to clients

Tags: android

We have the same application for several clients. This application, for security reasons, cannot be published to Google Play, so we distribute it manually to customers.

The problem is that every time there is a new version of the application we have to contact all customers and update all their applications.

Isn't there a way to have private applications on google play and give access to different clients so that they can download the updates for those applications?

I've seen this, but I'm not sure if it behaves like I expect: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en#runtest

Comment: Please check [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139?hl=en)

Comment: You can use fabric crashlytics beta, soon to be migrated to firebase beta

Comment: But this publish private application for my own organitzation (same @domain) and it's not my case.

Comment: There are several platforms like TestFairy or AppCenter. Which have an API to upload apps and a SDK that warns the user when a new distribution is available. It might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, there is an internal test app version available in the Play Store where you can upload your app version. Once uploaded you will have a private link available and only the people with access to that link will be able to download the app.

Comment: But this is also manual, because I have to send that link to all customers and hope that they will update the aplication. I'm looking something similar to google play updates, where customers get a notification when a new update is available.

Comment: With the internal test feature the app will be automatically updated like any app, but yes, you will have to send the link the first time to all your clients.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can publish as a "beta" version of the application https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180. You can define your clients as beta-testers and app would be visible on market only for them.

Answer (score -1):

I have an approach, Assume you have an .apk file in your website. every customer will download it from here. Now you have to make an API call whenever user will use your application to make sure that they are using the latest version of application by sending the version details to server. If the user is using an older version (This you will get from server/api response) block the screen and redirect them to server to download the new .apk.
You can store the response to a local/DB so they can not use your application in offline mode also.